# android Iterating through Views by Id

Tags: android, view, for-loop, loops

I have a layout the contains 4 TextViews with ids: "Name1", "Name2", "Name3", "Name4"

I would like to iterate on them with a for loop,
is there any way to do this?

something like

```
    for(int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
    {
        findViewById(R.id."Name" + i)
    }
```

I know that this code is far from being real, but any help?
Thank you!
Ron

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot do it like that because R.id.xyz is referencing a static int of a static class. It's not a string that can be concatenated like that. Also, your code ignores the return value of findViewById so it does nothing (though I realize you mentioned the code is far being real, but still an actual use case might help clarify what you're trying to do). R.id."Name" means nothing and will give you a compiler error.

To loop through you can do something like this:

```
int[] ids = {R.id.foo, R.id.bar};
```

then

```
for(int i = 0; i<ids.length; i++) {
View v = findViewById(ids[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can do that sort of. You cannot access an member of R.id using a string literal you must type out the variable name.
`R.id."Test"` is no good but `R.id.Test` is fine.

If you examine the type of `R.id.XYZ` you will find that it is simply an integer. There is no reason why you cannot perform basic arithmetic on `id` values.

However it doesn't really make sense to do so. When you build your APK the compiler automatically creates a static class called `R` that contains references to the various resources and assets contained in your APK, such as layouts, drawables, sounds, etc..

Just because you know that the integer value for R.id.button1 is X there is no guarantee that the integer value for R.id.button2 will be X+1, in fact it could be anything.

If you want to create a list of `TextViews` to iterate over consider adding them to a List and then iterating over the list. Like so:

```
ArrayList<TextView> list = new ArrayList<TextView>();
list.add( (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1) );
list.add( (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2) );
list.add( (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3) );
list.add( (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4) );

int size = list.getSize();
for (int i=0; i< size; i++)
{
     TextView tv = list.get(i);
     // Do something with tv like set its label to i
     tv.setText(Integer.toString(i));
}
```